# MYSQL leaking memory on "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, c, memory-leaks

**EDIT: Looks like the problem is in my C code,** since when I print all the SQL to a file, and then feed that in via the command line, the mysqld memory consumption is stable. It must be something that is being missed during the code segment I posted, but according to MYSQL documentation, mysql_store_result should pull the entire result from the server.

Original question for context, C code segment below:

I have 100 MYSQL tables, with 1017 columns each, with 630,000 rows each. I know that normally having this many columns would absolutely be the wrong approach, but for a personal project, it is the simplest solution for what I need to track.

I am doing an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement to set about 5 columns in each row, on every run of my C program, and using the primary key to address them. I do these UPDATEs in batches of 1k to 350k.

No inserts are ever done by this, since all the rows that I address already exist.

After about 20 minutes, the MYSQL process memory growth is pretty clear, since my swap starts being used more and more, and performance slows to a crawl. You can observe the mysqld process memory usage slowly climbing via top, even after only a few minutes. My calling program doesn't grow in memory usage during this process, by MYSQL ends up in the 90%+ range, with the rest in swap.

Additionally, even when I terminate my calling C program and let all the queries finish executing, mysqld is still holding on to a ton of memory, none appears to be getting released, not even that in the swap.

After each query has finished, I run this code in order to clear out the results (I don't use them for anything):

```
while (mysql_next_result(mysql) == 0)
{       
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    res = mysql_store_result(mysql);
    mysql_free_result(res);
}
```

An example of one of my UPDATE statements, for only 3 rows:

```
INSERT INTO data.test1_t1 (pkey,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) VALUES 
  (100000,1,1,1,1,1),
  (100001,2,2,2,2,2),
  (100002,3,3,3,3,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE v1=VALUES(v1),v2=VALUES(v2),v3=VALUES(v3),v4=VALUES(v4),v5=VALUES(v5)
```

My machine is a dedicated Ubuntu 16.04 install, with 32GB RAM and 32GB swap, with MYSQL version 5.7.17, with these modified options in the configuration file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

I am using the C API, issuing the queries with mysql_real_query. This program is the only thing accessing the database, and the problem isn't hard to reproduce, so is easy to test. Any suggestions would be extremely welcome.

Comment: Is the MySQL server using  too much memory or is your C client code? This question needs to be pruned down to something more digestible.

Comment: The MYSQL server is using too much memory, my C program isn't using much at all. I'll add this, and try to trim it down some, thanks.

Comment: In my experience the `mysqld` process only uses as much memory as it's configured to, and while I've seen a lot of quirky behaviour over the years, a memory leak would be new. Are you sure there's no buffer configured to some ridiculously huge size?

Comment: Still fixing up the edit, but I am sure that the only settings I modified are those three that I listed.

Comment: There's something immediately suspicious about a table with >1000 columns, so I think if this is a MySQL bug you're more likely to run into trouble by being so deep into edge case territory. Does this memory problem manifest when runing SQL via the `mysql` command-line tool? What about via `LOAD DATA INFILE` using a CSV source? You need to try and narrow down the circumstances under which this emerges.

Comment: Ok, Good idea. I'm going to try outputting all the queries to a single file, and then feeding in the file via the command line, and seeing if it still happens.  Will probably take about 25 minutes for me to complete this test.

Comment: I output all the SQL to a file, and fed that in to mysql on the command line, and it seems like things are stable! Thank you. So, the question becomes, "what could I be doing wrong in my C program to make the memory stay resident in the mysqld process?" Is it acceptable for me to edit the original post with this info, to focus it one what I could be doing wrong in the C world?

Comment: There's not enough C code there to give you an answer. I think if you can create a minimal, reproducible C program that trashes your server that's something that should be forwarded to the MySQL development team as a bug report.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, issue still exists, let me work on it some more.